# 1Pc 2Users give access to only one user through MAC Address

Tags: server, ip-address, mac-address

I need to let a user access server only from a specific MAC, so he wont be able to access server from another device.
Can any one give me hint how can i achieve that ?

Comment: Put a firewall in place that filters based on MAC address.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to achieve this
You can of course limit access by protocol/IP/port (with `iptables`), or at the application level (including IP, with `tcpwrappers`). You can also limit access based on MAC (with `ebtables`).
But I am affraid there are no solutions linking user information and MAC address. Too far in the network stack to be usable, perhaps.
What is the exact problem that you are trying to solve by limiting access by MAC and UserID? 
Consider a solution like this: initialy, every computer gets a 'temporary' IP from an unprvileged network. That IP does not entitle the user to use any services. Then the user logs in , and after a  sucesfull log-in, a new IP from privileged network is issued to him. This IP is specific to this user. From now on the user access can be controlled based solely on his IP.
This will require VLANs and some provisioning made on switches. See [Windows server - assign IP by username](https://serverfault.com/questions/475335/windows-server-assign-ip-by-username) for a similar case.

Comment: A Company wants that they/re employers only  access there server from there own PC and through other colleagues pc, I hope im clear!!

Comment: I have extended my answer